# sort with limit in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sorting

I created a table which fetches and displays the records from the database with given Limit and Offset. Now i am trying to apply the sorting (desc/asc) in the table when clicked on the heading of any field of table. My purpose is to sort only the results i get with limit and offset but instead it is sorting the entire table and replacing the previous results with the new.

### Controller

```
public function dummy(){
    $field = "";
    $sort = "";
    $limit= 2;
    $id= 5;
    $field = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $sort = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->sortData($field,$sort,$limit,$id);
    $this->load->view('admin/dummy',$data);
}
```

### Model

```
public function sortData($field,$sort,$limit,$id){
        $this->db->limit($limit,$id);
        $this->db->order_by($field,$sort);
        $query = $this->db->get('employee');
        return $query->result();
        }
```

Here is the example of records which i get before sorting

```
Firstname|Lastname|BirthDay |Email     |Mobile
Wendy    |moore   |28/7/1990|abc@a.com |xxx
Brad     |hoff    |14/3/1985|xyz@.com  |zzz
```

The result i want after sorting based on firstname is

```
Firstname|Lastname|BirthDay |Email     |Mobile
Brad     |hoff    |14/3/1985|xyz@.com  |zzz
Wendy    |moore   |28/7/1990|abc@a.com |xxx
```

The result i am getting now is

```
Firstname|Lastname|BirthDay |Email     |Mobile
Anna     |Fox     |1/8/1995 |xyz@.com  |zzz
Berry    |Alan    |9/10/1992|abc@a.com |xxx
```

See it is sorting the entire table and replacing the results based on previous offset.

### My URL for sorting

```
            <?php if($this->uri->segment(5)!= 'desc'){ ?>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard/'.$geturl.'/firstName/desc');?>">
<?php } else
        { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard/'.$geturl.'/firstName/asc');?>">
    <?php } ?> FirstName</a>
```

Comment: MYSQL does these things in a specific order. 1-select, 2-sort selected rows, 3-Limit what it returns. So to do what you want you will have to sort the result in PHP and not MYSQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly So i need to do the sort after getting result. Well thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SamB your `$field` and `$sort` are empty variables

Comment: @Spartan I am getting them with the uri->segments. Check it.

Comment: @SamB are you sure those assigned correctly ?? print and check those values

Comment: @Spartan I had checked them. I declared them null as default i.e, before sorting. When i clicked for sorting they are getting values.

Comment: what are those values show it please

Comment: @SamB sort should be `DESC` or `ASC`

Comment: @RiggsFolly please post your comment in answers. I'll mark it as accepted. It may help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('employee');
$this->db->order_by($field,$sort);
$this->db->limit($limit,$id);
$query=$this->db->get();
```

---

**FYI**

1. `$sort` should be **DESC** or **ASC**
2. In `limit` you have set 2 values. It act as `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

---

**Links**

1. [`order_by()` in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results)
2. [`limit()`  in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

Comment: <?php if($this->uri->segment(5)!= 'desc'){ ?>
   <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard/'.$geturl.'/firstName/desc');?>"><?php }else{ ?>
   <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard/'.$geturl.'/firstName/asc');?>"><?php } ?>FirstName</a>

Comment: This is my link which i send when sorting. Sorry i mistakenly write 5 in previous comment

Comment: @SamB If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: actually according to my requirement RiggsFolly answer helped me. The answer you provided, I already implemented that in my code above.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I wonder how to add a WHERE clause to your procedure. A WHERE with null check. Greetings A. Valter E

Comment: @ValterEkholm next to `from` add `$this->db->where(<condition>);`